# Managing multiple TCP clients in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a Node.JS app which connects to multiple different servers and waits on data from them.  However, I am not sure the best way to go about it in Node.  How do I manage 'data' events from multiple socket clients?  When the event handler fires for new data, how do I associate that with the server it is connected to?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the node website [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

> Node maintains several connections per server to make HTTP requests.
>   This function allows one to transparently issue requests.

Every time you call `http.request` it creates a new [`http.ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) that is distinct for that request, so the following code works perfectly as expected:

```
var options1 = {hostname: 'www.google.com', port: 80, path: '/', method: 'GET'};
var options2 = {hostname: 'en.wikipedia.com', port: 80, path: '/', method: 'GET'};

var req1 = http.request(options1, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS Req1: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS Req1: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY Req1: ' + chunk);
    });
});
var req2 = http.request(options2, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS Req2: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS Req2: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY Req2: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req1.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request1: ' + e.message);
});
req2.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request2: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req1.write('data\n');
req1.write('data\n');
req1.end();

req2.write('data\n');
req2.write('data\n');
req2.end();
```